# I'm not getting "install alongside windows10" option and nothing seems to be helping

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, windows-10

As the tittle says, I'm not getting the "install alongside windows" option when I want to install ubuntu 20.04, only something else and erase disk.

I'm using ASUS Windows 10 Legacy BIOS with 8GB of RAM. I've so much attempted to disable fast startup, disable secure boot, disabling CSM but the usb drive is no recognized then.
I've partitioned around 35GB of free space. The disk is formatted as basic.

Did anyone had the same problem? What could be the issue and how to resolve it since nothing seems to be helping?

Comment: When you made the boot Live Media USB did you set it for BIOS mode? Are you sure your Windows install is using BIOS mode and not EFI? If the Live Media is using a different mode then the already install OS they do not see each other.

Comment: BTW 35 gig for Ubuntu is a bit low.

Comment: @David Yes I did set it for BIOS and my windows was installed in BIOS. 
I will try to increase the size to see if that would help.

Comment: No it wont affect the install. You would just run out of space when using the OS quite quickly. What tool did you use to make the Live media? Did you verify the ISO before making the USB?. https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu#1-overview

Comment: I've formatted my USB stick(16GB) and burned the ISO using Rufus